# I receive the following error when I tried to trigger a build from Visual Studio 2017 that is connected to TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, msbuild

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets (316): The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Builds\1\AutoDeployers\WebApplicationForAutoDeploy1_Main_Build\src\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\build..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Builds\1\AutoDeployers\WebApplicationForAutoDeploy1_Main_Build\src\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

[Screenshot goes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DNF4.png)
what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you build the project successfully with the local Visual Studio 2017? How did you set in your build definition?

Comment: Yes, I could build my project successfully on my local machine using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this fixed my issue

Installing MS Build Tools 2015 on my build machine resolved the issue

followed the below link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72f1eb71-9acf-448e-ad29-e500bb96cebd/could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembly?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0):

Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Try to build the project in VS 2017 directly to check if that works.
- Check your build definition, make sure you have added the `Nuget Restore` task to restore the referenced packages.
- Check the build log to see if the referenced packages are restored
  correctly.
- Enable the **Clean** option (set clean to **true**) in **Repository** tab
  and **VS build** step, try build again.
- If you are using VS build task, just try to use `MSBuild` task
  instead. (Manually specify the msbuild.exe path if needed)
- Try to build with Visual Studio 2015 (Select Visual Studio Version in
  VS build step)

Also reference this article : [Resolved: The “Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc” task could not be loaded from the assembly](https://kx.cloudingenium.com/programming/net/resolved-microsoft-codeanalysis-buildtasks-csc-task-not-loaded-assembly/)

Comment: Hi andy...thanks for the response....I'm using XAML build definition to build the solution. The solution successfully builds on my local machine(Visual Studio 2017). I tried following the same approach that you suggested in the reference article, but it didn't work for me. The error still persists(note: I'm using XAML build definition)